# Android Studio Activity wont start if dont finish()

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to run LogIn activity from MainActivity  but if I dont add FINISH() after
startActivityForResult, intent wont start

```
      on MainActivity
        **pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       Boolean mojpin = pref.getBoolean("PinLock",false);
         if(mojpin && loged==false){
      Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AppPinLock.class);
      MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(i,1);
          finish();
       }**
   On LogIn Activity
            **String mojpin = getPassword();
            if(mojpin!= ""){
               String mojpin2 = pass.getText().toString();
                if(mojpin.equals(mojpin2)){
                    naslov.setText("Pin is ok");
                 
                  Intent i = new Intent(AppPinLock.this,MainActivity.class);
                  setResult(1, i);
                   startActivity(i); //if I dont add this wont back to MainActivity
                  finish();**
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, You shouldn't close MainActivity after calling startActivity();
Explanation: If you start an Activity in MainActivity, the Method

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Will be called. But if you call finish(); after calling the other Activity in the MainActivity, Android instantly Terminates the MainActivity completly and you can't get back until you call the MainActivity again. Example Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class));
        //DO NOT use finish(); here!!! (It will kill this Activity after launching Actiivty2)
    }
}
```

Activity2

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        finish(); //this will close this Activity and you will get back to the last Activity. (In this case MainActivity)
    }
}
```